# How to make bootable usb from Windows XP x64 installation ISO?

Tags: windows-xp, boot, usb, 64-bit, iso-image

I tried various stuff but none of them worked. Like RuFus, ISO2USB. RMprepusb tells me in the description that for Windows XP installation I also need to modify some files so it can't directly make it to boot. Any ideas what those files are?

WinToFlashLite on the other hand ( I tried it on Windows 10 ) fails in the process telling me that it can't lock my usb flash device (I tried closing all running programs and even un-mounting the usb but without result).

I also tried following the command suggested in this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/2952/boot-and-install-windows-from-a-usb-thumb-drive) but without luck too.

Another thing I did was simply copying over the ISO data over my USB in the chance that somehow my PC-BIOS will be able to boot it up (using linux 'dd' command).

I'm really giving it up right now. I also always wondered why there isn't some unified way of booting El Torito ISO images without burning them to disks (but maybe I'll make another question about that)?

Comment: I managed to get XP x86 to install from USB. It’s a complete package that uses a virtual floppy disk image (mounted with Grub, accessibly via a slipstreamed driver) containing storage drivers for many systems. Unfortunately, I’ll have access to this information again only after Christmas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem using this [tool](http://www.easy2boot.com/). I simply followed the instructions on the site and copied over my Win Xp X64 ISO file into the Windows Xp Installation folder on the prepared usb.

This tool simply loaded the iso image into system RAM and executed it.

Comment: easy2boot tool contains virus. you can scan it and see for yourself at virustotal.com

Comment: @julius This is a serious allegation. Please explain what *exactly* you have observed; ideally, link to the precise SHA1 on Virustotal.

Comment: https://virustotal.com/en/file/f6bae86c4c27710c50702460ccd75d1d19be31625b2938c1385eee695c21c587/analysis/ is `Easy2Boot_v1.91.exe`.  9 engines out of 63 report it as unwanted or malicious but the majority of them simply seem to indicate that it's unwanted (PUA).

Comment: https://virustotal.com/en/file/852f68dd82cb512b76ba35bc6f8d2de6b734ef15a230d3418e297586ea6023b2/analysis/ similarly indicates 11/62 for the DPMS version.

Comment: @julius Go to [_False-Positive Virus/PUP/PUA Detection_](http://www.easy2boot.com/download/): "... good AV scanners such as Avira, Avast, AVG, Kaspersky, McAfee, Symantec, Sophos, etc. should not report a problem with the download (Sophos may report a PUA = Potentially Unwanted Application - this is NOT a virus). Due to the nature of SWITCH_E2B.exe which requires Administrator priveleges and writes directly to the MBR of USB disks, this program does trigger several AV false positives however."